# How to successfully invalidate a session when logging out in Spring MVC

Tags: session, spring-mvc, session-variables

I have tried several times to invalidate the session. I have used the following code to remove the items from the session and invalidating the session itself.

```
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if(session != null) {
        session.removeAttribute("user");
    }
    session.invalidate();
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Somehow, when another user logs in, the previous user's details are loaded onto the page. I didn't use Spring Security not wanting to complicate things. I'm not sure how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to set the userDetails object in sessionObject using **@sessionAttribute()** in contrller. While doing logOut operation, set the userDetails object to null. In Jsp check if userDetails is null or not using jstl. This is really simple and will fit for your requirement.